# Import Wikipedia's indices into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wikipedia, dump

For my research I should import Russian Wikipedia's dump into Elasticsearch 2.2. But instead of importing dump I decided to work with indices published by Wikimedia (http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/). To work with it I found an article https://www.elastic.co/blog/loading-wikipedia and tried to use author's scripts for my problem (just replaced some export-statements). But there's a problem in the Step 2.

It is my version of script for Step 2:

```
export es=localhost:9200
export site=ru.wikipedia.org
export index=ruwiki

curl -XDELETE $es/$index?pretty

curl -s 'https://'$site'/w/api.php?action=cirrus-settings-dump&format=json&formatversion=2' |
jq '{ analysis: .content.page.index.analysis, number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 }' |
curl -XPUT $es/$index?pretty -d @-

curl -s 'https://'$site'/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json&formatversion=2' |
jq .content |
sed 's/"index_analyzer"/"analyzer"/' |
sed 's/"position_offset_gap"/"position_increment_gap"/' |
curl -XPUT $es/$index/_mapping/page?pretty -d @-
```

And the result

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
      "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: mapping source is empty;"
    } ],
    "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: mapping source is empty;"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I also tried to use author's script just for test. There's the same error. I don't know what to do. Please, help to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia dumps are currently exported from ElasticSearch 1.7.5. Most likely (I haven't tested) the current mapping is not compatible with ES 2.2. It is likely worthwhile to try using the older version of ES.

Edit: The latest dumps are now compatible with elasticsearch 2.x